# node-gyp err on install for npm integer

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, discord.js, node-gyp

Node Version: node: v11.10.0 and npm: 6.7.0
Platform: Windows 10
Module: integer

Every time I attempt to install integer, I get the following error.

```
PS C:\Users\will_\OneDrive\Desktop\bot-test> npm i integer

> integer@2.1.0 install C:\Users\will_\OneDrive\Desktop\bot-test\node_modules\integer
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\will_\OneDrive\Desktop\bot-test\node_modules\integer>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:427:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\will_\OneDrive\Desktop\bot-test\node_modules\integer
gyp ERR! node -v v11.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of bufferutil@^3.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of erlpack@discordapp/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of opusscript@^0.0.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of sodium@^2.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.7.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of uws@^9.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bot-test@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN bot-test@1.0.0 license should be a valid SPDX license expression

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 7
npm ERR! integer@2.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 7
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the integer@2.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\will_\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-28T07_57_21_798Z-debug.log
```

I looked up the error on google and got different results. I have tried different things from reinstalling Microsoft Visual Studio, to editing files in my registry. I have tried a bunch of things and asked for help on other forums as well. I just can not seem to figure this out on my own and would appreciate some.

Answer (score 7):

---

> Please note that the official [Node.js for Windows installer](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) can now automatically install the required tools. That's likely a much better option than the module listed here (`windows-build-tools`).

---

(Read above notice, the offical node.js installer will now take care of this)

I would suggest you to install the build tools for node.
These will help you compile node-gyp packages and most likely fix your error.
Simply start PowerShell as Administrator and run:

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
```

Or, if you are using Yarn:

```
yarn global add windows-build-tools
```

NPM Package: [`windows-build-tools`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools)

> You could also install `Python 2.7` and `Visual C++ Build Tools` manually but windows-build-tools handles this all for you!

Answer (score 5):

I got a similar exception when switching computer. I simply removed `package-lock.json` and then it worked.

Answer (score 3):

After stucking on these kind of error for many hours I finally figured out. Always remember to have a closer look at error which start with:

**gyp ERR! stack Error**: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT

This means that the path of Microsoft Visual Studio is wrong (you can check  by pasting C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe in explorer address bar), so to rectify just use:

```
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin
```

to rectify the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing node-gyp as Global.

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

and also you need to have build tools installed in your system, for installing build tools execute this instructions in your terminal.

```
npm install build-tools  -g
```

This should fix your problem, if haven't yet fixed try rebooting.