# Npm install not installing because of node-gyp

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to install the `filepreview` module with `npm`. But it always gives error. Here is the error:

```
D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator>npm install filepreview

> fibers@1.0.15 install D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js


D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )
gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
node-gyp exited with code: 7
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN PalettenzettelGenerator@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fibers@1.0.15 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.15 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ibrahim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-02T08_17_55_828Z-debug.log
```

I've searched for it, generally says it's about `node-gyp`. My node is v10.16.0. I've also installed Python 2.7. My vs version is 2019.

Is it true that it's only about `node-gyp` module. If so, is there any other solution to preview a file as png in Node.js

**EDIT**

I've uninstalled VS2019 and installed VS2017 Build Tools. But still gives another error:

```
D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator>npm install filepreview

> fibers@1.0.15 install D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js


D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )
Bu çözümde projeler tek tek derlenir. Paralel bir derlemeyi etkinleştirmek için lütfen "/m" anahtarını ekleyin.
  fibers.cc
  coroutine.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(122): error C2660: 'v8::String::NewFromOneByte': işlev 2 bağımsız değişken almıyor [D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\
fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
  c:\users\ibrahim\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\10.16.0\include\node\v8.h(2802): note: 'v8::String::NewFromOneByte' bildirimine bakın (kaynak dosyası derleniyor ..\src\fibers.cc)
d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(126): error C2660: 'v8::String::NewFromOneByte': işlev 2 bağımsız değişken almıyor [D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\
fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
  c:\users\ibrahim\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\10.16.0\include\node\v8.h(2802): note: 'v8::String::NewFromOneByte' bildirimine bakın (kaynak dosyası derleniyor ..\src\fibers.cc)
d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(406): warning C4996: 'v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value': kullanım dışı olarak bildirildi [D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_mo
dules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
  c:\users\ibrahim\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\10.16.0\include\node\v8.h(2891): note: 'v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value' bildirimine bakın
d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(433): error C2661: 'v8::Function::NewInstance': hiçbir aşırı yüklenmiş işlev 2 bağımsız değişken almaz [D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synch
ronize\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(433): error C2672: 'uni::Return': eşleşen aşırı yüklenmiş işlev bulunamadı [D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\b
uild\fibers.vcxproj]
d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(621): error C2512: 'v8::TryCatch': kullanılabilir uygun varsayılan oluşturucu yok [D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\f
ibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
  c:\users\ibrahim\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\10.16.0\include\node\v8.h(8529): note: 'v8::TryCatch' bildirimine bakın (kaynak dosyası derleniyor ..\src\fibers.cc)
d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(628): warning C4996: 'v8::Script::Compile': kullanım dışı olarak bildirildi [D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\
build\fibers.vcxproj]
  c:\users\ibrahim\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\10.16.0\include\node\v8.h(1255): note: 'v8::Script::Compile' bildirimine bakın
d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(643): warning C4996: 'v8::TryCatch::StackTrace': kullanım dışı olarak bildirildi [D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fi
bers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
  c:\users\ibrahim\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\10.16.0\include\node\v8.h(8593): note: 'v8::TryCatch::StackTrace' bildirimine bakın
d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(741): error C2661: 'v8::Value::ToNumber': hiçbir aşırı yüklenmiş işlev 0 bağımsız değişken almaz [D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize
\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(793): error C2660: 'v8::Object::SetAccessor': işlev 2 bağımsız değişken almıyor [D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fib
ers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
  c:\users\ibrahim\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\10.16.0\include\node\v8.h(3348): note: 'v8::Object::SetAccessor' bildirimine bakın (kaynak dosyası derleniyor ..\src\fibers.cc)
d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(794): error C2664: 'v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::Context>,v8::Local<v8::Name>,v8::AccessorNameGetterCallback,v8::AccessorNameSetterCallback,v8::M
aybeLocal<v8::Value>,v8::AccessControl,v8::PropertyAttribute,v8::SideEffectType)' : 2 bağımsız değişkeni 'uni::FunctionType (__cdecl *)(v8::Local<v8::String>,const uni::GetterCallbackInfo &)' değerinden 'v8::Local<v8::Name>' değerine dönüştürülemez [D:\Program Files\nodejs\Pal
ettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
  d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(794): note: Kaynak türünü hiçbir oluşturucu alamadı veya oluşturucu aşırı yük çözümü belirsizdi
d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(795): error C2660: 'v8::Object::SetAccessor': işlev 2 bağımsız değişken almıyor [D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fib
ers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
  c:\users\ibrahim\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\10.16.0\include\node\v8.h(3348): note: 'v8::Object::SetAccessor' bildirimine bakın (kaynak dosyası derleniyor ..\src\fibers.cc)
d:\program files\nodejs\palettenzettelgenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\src\coroutine.cc(138): warning C4552: '!': ifade sonucu kullanılmıyor [D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj
]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:196:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Program Files\nodejs\PalettenzettelGenerator\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN PalettenzettelGenerator@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fibers@1.0.15 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.15 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ibrahim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-02T23_04_29_295Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Had you searched the node-gyp issue tracker, or google, you probably would have discover that (for reasons _no one understands_, including you and I) node-gyp only works with python 2.7 - but looking at your error log.

Comment: I've installed python 2.7 also, it's still giving the node-gyp error

Comment: Have you set [npm configs](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows)?

Comment: When I look to python version via 'python -V', the version is 2.7.16. Also I've set the configs

Comment: So, let's keep reading the log. `gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT` says MSBuild.exe doesn't exist where your path/env/etc suggest it should exist. Have you fixed that? Also, have you visited https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp as the log tells you to, in order to see if this is a known issue, or even a documented event that has a documented solution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have come across this same issue in the past. Here is the solution. You may need to restart your machine several times to clear all the errors.

Solution:

```
1. Install Install VC++ Build Tools  2017 and while installing select V140 from the side menu

2. Install Python 2.7, and add it to your PATH

3. npm config set python python2.7 --global

4. npm config set python C:\Python27\python.exe --global

5. npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global

6. set VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140


**Note:  If you still face error > most likely the problem is node-sass is not installed**
```

After this step you have to restart your machine

```
7. Install the latest versions of Python

8. As Admin:
$ cd "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm"
$ npm install node-gyp

9. $ npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global

Note: that I have VS 2017, but configuring it as ver 2017 won't work. Not sure why.

    10. As Admin:
$ npm install -g node-sass

And finally, one last check:
$ node-sass -v
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: As @ragavan-rajan said, when I make the configurations and install the synchronize with `npm install https://github.com/alexeypetrushin/synchronize.git`, filepreview successfully installed. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Hi @RagavanRajan, tried these steps but it did not work. Here I have more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64578469/gyp-err-build-error-if-not-defined-npm-config-node-gyp

Comment: Hi @Andres, Could you pls confirm what is the step 1 you have on your machine. Looks like you have installed different version of VC++.

Comment: I am sure that is the issue. However will wait for your reply

Answer (score 4):

I am running Windows 11. I followed [the steps in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57763427/1175496), but using the values from this [answer on node-gyp GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1753#issuecomment-500093610)

> Can confirm this setup works:
>
> ```
> msbuild_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"
> msvs_version = "2017"
> ```

Except for me, the `msbuild_path` was different; my `msbuild_path` value is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

Therefore my steps look like this:

1. Install VC++ Build Tools  (these are installed as part of [node's Windows installation (MSI) wizard](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/install-node.js-windows-step-5.png))
2. Install Python and add it to your PATH (again this was installed as part of node's wizard)
3. `npm config set python python2.7 --global`
4. `npm config set python C:\Python27\python.exe --global`
5. `npm config set msvs_version 2017 --global`
6. `npm config set msbuild_path "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"`

Some [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54930595/1175496) suggest installing `windows-build-tools`, which should take care of steps 1 and 2, I don't think this helped me (because node *itself* installs VS Code and Python), but it might help others (do this step first):

`npm install --global windows-build-tools`

Comment: The answer worked fine for me on Windows 10 and Node 16.x!

Answer (score 3):

It's node version problem. I'm currently on the [latest feature version (Current Version)](https://nodejs.org/en/). The newer node is not supported yet.
To solve the problem, you could switch to [LTS version](https://nodejs.org/en/) which is normally fully supported.

Easy switch would be (If you are using [brew](https://brew.sh/)):

```
brew unlink node
```

and then link the [node lts verion](https://nodejs.org/en/) (right now is node@12) as the following:

```
brew install node@12 && brew link --overwrite node@12 --force
```

That solved for me.

Answer (score 2):

Simple fix worked for me is:

I installed Python 3.7 and installed Visual Studio version 2017 from https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202017

Also installed recommended updates.

And then I set npm config set msvs_version 2017 --global.

Answer (score 2):

After spending more than 3 days finally found the solution at https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/03/27/node-gyp-windows/

It worked when I ran "**npm install -no-optional**"
The -no-optional flag ensures that npm installs only the required packages.

A quick note : I followed all the steps listed in https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows and finally ran "npm install -no-optional"

Answer (score 1):

It's a node version problem.
In my case, I was trying to install node-sass:4.13.0 with Node version 14 which is not compatible.
I uninstalled Node14, cleared npm cache, and installed Node 12.8 version with Chocolately. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off the automatic update from visual studio of npm's packages

Answer (score 0):

After trying many solutions, including the accepted answer, for me it was quite a simple solution.

I removed `node-sass` from `package.json` of the project I was working on and reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for :** "gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT"

1. **npm install --global windows-build-tools**

   ```
                     OR
   ```

   **npm --vs2017 install --global windows-build-tools** ( In **admin power shell** )

   please wait for "**All done!**" message display on cmd if success
2. **Install Python 2.7**
   https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-275/
3. **npm config set python python2.7 --global**
4. **npm config set python C:\Python27\python.exe --global**
5. **npm config set msbuild_path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"**

   **Note :** Please check your build tool 2017 path location

   **(Visual Studio Build Tool 2017)**
6. **npm install**

Thanks,

**Viral Kalaria**

Answer (score 0):

For **Visual Studio 2022**, the `VCTargetsPath` must be set to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\<EDITION>\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\`.

Change `<EDITION>` to the VS edition you're running (e.g. `Professional` or `Community`).

Answer (score -1):

Setting the MSBuild path worked for me. It was not able to recognize my VS2019 MSbuild path.

npm config set msvs_version 2017
npm config set msbuild_path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"

Comment: There's already an accepted answer, and it suggests a similar config change to what you propose. Note that the accepted answer also talks about MSBuild:
`6. set VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140`