# How to install zookeeper node module offline?

Tags: node.js, apache-zookeeper, yarnpkg, offline, node-gyp

I've been trying to install [zookeeper node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zookeeper) offline (behind corporate walls).
Usually, I use [this script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-package-downloader) to download modules, and then publish it (and all it's dependencies) to verdaccio in my closed network - and it works.
With zookeeper, it uploads it to verdaccio successfully but when I try to add it to my project using

```
yarn add zookeeper --update-checksums
```

I get an error when an automatic node-gyp rebuild is triggered -

```
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.3/node-v12.16.3- 
headers.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
```

After reading the [following issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/812) I've downloaded the missing headers, entered it to my closed network and then used

```
yarn config set nodedir SOME_LOCAL_FOLDER
```

I placed node-v12.16.3-headers.tar.gz in SOME_LOCAL_FOLDER and then tried to run yarn add again.
Then, I got an error saying I don't have visual studio installed, [like in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879150/how-can-i-solve-error-gypgyp-errerr-find-vsfind-vs-msvs-version-not-set-from-c). I installed visual studio 2015 and the error went away.
But now, I'm getting a new error saying

```
SOME_LOCAL_FOLDER/common.gypi not found (cwd: DEVELOPING_FOLDER\node_modules\zookeeper) while reading 
includes of binding.gyp wile trying to load 
binding.gyp.
```

I feel like I'm going in circles. Did anyone come across this problems with the same module or with a different one?

node version - 12.16.3
yarn version - 1.7.0