# npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, msbuild, npm-install

When I run npm install facing same issue with new versions, Any one please help. I have installed vs 2017 and 2022 And also tried npm config set msvs_version 2022

```
    gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config 
gyp ERR! find VS running in VS Command Prompt, installation path is:  
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022"
gyp ERR! find VS - will only use this version
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.2.32519.379) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v143
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.19041.0
gyp ERR! find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.2.32519.379) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v143
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.19041.0
gyp ERR! find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1974) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
gyp ERR! find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"
gyp ERR! find VS - could not find MSBuild in registry for this version
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\manju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\manju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\manju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\manju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\manju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:396:20
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\manju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\manju\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\manju\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\web development\skuad_1\talent-view-service\node_modules\node-rdkafka
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN @nestjs/mapped-types@0.1.1 requires a peer of class-transformer@^0.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nestjs/mapped-types@0.1.1 requires a peer of class-validator@^0.11.1 || ^0.12.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN acorn-jsx@5.2.0 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN apollo-graphql@0.4.5 requires a peer of graphql@^14.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.2.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.16.0 || ^6.8.0 || ^7.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.      
npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@2.22.1 requires a peer of eslint@^2 || ^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.  
npm WARN graphql-subscriptions@1.1.0 requires a peer of graphql@^0.10.5 || ^0.11.3 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN graphql-upload@8.1.0 requires a peer of graphql@0.13.1 - 14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN http-aws-es@6.0.0 requires a peer of elasticsearch@^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})        

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-rdkafka@2.9.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-rdkafka@2.9.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\manju\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-26T07_05_19_604Z-debug.log
```

Any one please help me here

When I run npm install facing same issue with new versions, Any one please help. I have installed vs 2017 and 2022 And also tried npm config set msvs_version 2022

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this Article: Related thread
[npm ERR! gyp ERR! when installing node sass in windows 11 with Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70082657/npm-err-gyp-err-when-installing-node-sass-in-windows-11-with-visual-studio-202)

**Upgrading node-sass worked for me**.

Things to check:

1. Including the "Desktop development with C++" while VS installation.(you can modify existing installation)
2. npm config set msbuild_path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
   npm config set msvs_version 2022
   3.[Updating node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/main/docs/Updating-npm-bundled-node-gyp.md)
3. npm install --save-dev node-sass

Comment: it says 'msbuild_path` is not a valid npm option'