# package requires node-gyp and i can't get it to work (Windows 10)

Tags: javascript, node.js

**What I've tried**

Downloading the windows-build-tools package

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools --vs2015
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Manually installing the tools from this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159 and doing `npm config set msvs_version 2015 –global`.

Installing python2.7 and doing `npm config set python python2.7`

**The Error**

```
C:\Users\Thaddea>npm install gpu.js --global
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Thaddea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gpu.js\node_modules\gl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.15 found at "C:\Users\Thaddea\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2022
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS unknown version "undefined" found at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1745) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - "2017"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Thaddea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gpu.js\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Thaddea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gpu.js\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Thaddea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gpu.js\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Thaddea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gpu.js\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Thaddea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gpu.js\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Thaddea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gpu.js\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Thaddea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gpu.js\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Thaddea\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\gpu.js\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Thaddea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gpu.js\node_modules\gl
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Thaddea\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-14T16_00_06_174Z-debug-0.log
```

Thank you for reading. Please tell me what to do now..
I'm a bit new to the programming scene is all.

Comment: Node should be [installing all of this for you](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools). Have you just tried reinstalling the latest version?

Comment: I reinstalled it and it still doesnt work... But I set the msys_version to 2017 and the package installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve error gypgyp ERR!ERR! find VSfind VS msvs\_version not set from command line or npm config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879150/how-can-i-solve-error-gypgyp-errerr-find-vsfind-vs-msvs-version-not-set-from-c)