# Running 'npm install' : Node-gyp error - MSBUILD.exe failed with exit code 1

Tags: node.js, npm

I am attempting to run `npm install` to prepare a project to compile angular code, but I can't get it to work. I've tried various solutions I've found online, and nothing seems to work. Here's the relevant section from the log files:

```
...
npm ERR! gyp verb using MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\[path1]\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\[path2]\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\[path1]\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\[path1]\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

`node version` gives me this, which might be helpful info:

```
{
  npm: '8.4.1',
  node: '16.13.2',
  v8: '9.4.146.24-node.14',
  uv: '1.42.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.18.1',
  modules: '93',
  nghttp2: '1.45.1',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.4',
  openssl: '1.1.1l+quic',
  cldr: '39.0',
  icu: '69.1',
  tz: '2021a',
  unicode: '13.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
  nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
}
```

My setup came from installing `node-v16.13.2-x64.msi` and letting it install Chocolatey to install the supporting software. It installed Python 3.10 and Visual Studio Build Tools 2019.
However, it seems that `npm install` is asking for Python 2.7 (which I had to install manually).

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59650109/running-npm-install-node-gyp-error-msbuild-exe-failed-with-exit-code-1) and attempted to install the suggested `node-v11.14.0-x64.msi`. After installing that and running `npm install`, I got errors about having an outdated version of node, so I reinstalled with version 16.13.2.

I have also tried pointing npm to use Visual Studio 2017 instead of 2019, but got the same error in my logs.

Is there anything else I could do to get past this annoying problem? Or a way to increase the debug that I'm getting back?

Comment: You are installing a module that contains a binary that must be compiled (`node-sass`). Usually this kind of error would be because of incompatibility between the Node version, `node-gyp` or something similar. Try to install it and build it manually. `node-gyp` has a `-v` option when building from the command line.