# gyp ERR! build error - if not defined npm_config_node_gyp

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio, npm, package.json

After I run "npm install" I get these errors, I've ran "npm install --g --production windows-build-tools", I've also deleted node_modules, package-lock.json
and installed Visual Studio community 2019 but still have the same issue...

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\GitHub\myRepo\node_modules\snappy> if not defined npm_config_node_gyp
"C:\Users\myuser\Documents\GitHub\myRepo\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
 else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
```

```
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.7.30621.155) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"
gyp ERR! find VS - could not find MSBuild in registry for this version
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:20
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1047:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\Users\myuser\Documents\GitHub\myRepo\node_modules\\node_modules\\node\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\myuser\Documents\GitHub\myRepo\node_modules\snappy
gyp ERR! node -v v14.10.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

**Nodejs version that I'm using is: v12.8.1 and
NPM version: 6.10.2**

What should I do to remove that error after running "npm install"?

Comment: Try downloading Microsoft Video Studio 2015 2017 and 2019, and when you install each check the box that asks if you want to install desktop development c++ tools.

Comment: has anyone answer? I get the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I suggest installing dependencies with the command using power-shell in administrative mode npm install --global windows-build-tools